# open word template and run autonew from c#

Tags: c#, .net, macros, ms-word

I can open a .dot template from a hyperlink fine,
but it opens read-only and does not run the autonew macro.
Is there a setting or something obvious Im missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that's a security feature of Word to prevent macro viruses.  You could this after the document has been created:

```
wordobj.Run("autonew");
```

However, if there are multiple macros loaded called "autonew", then you can't be sure it will run yours.

Comment: Does it show as a .doc file in the title bar of Word?  Or as a new document (eg "Document1")?

Comment: after asking for confirmation of opening the file word displayes the [filename].dot (read only) in the titlebar.
I know i mentioned .doc earlier but after rebooting its as above.

thanks